# Angular (keydown.tab) stops further execution

Tags: html, angular

I have implemented a search Searchbox in my angular application.
If I type something in the input field, it opens a custom dropdown beneath the input.
If I press the tab key, I expect the dropdown to close and that the next input element is being focused.

It only closes the dropdown but the next field is not being focused.

```
<div class="main">
  <div class="select">
    <input class="input" placeholder="Suchtext eingeben" *ngIf="!selected" (focus)="isOpened = true" (keydown.enter)="selectItem(filteredData[0] || undefined)" (keydown.tab)="isOpened=false" (click)="isOpened = true" [(ngModel)]="searchText" (ngModelChange)="filterItems()">
  </div>
  <div class="drop-down">...</div>
</div>
```

Does the (blur) block the further execution? If yes, why is that so?

Comment: I think stopEventpropagation or preventDefault is what you should look for.

Comment: I actually do not want to stop it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to include `true` in the event handler to denote to propagate the event.

```html
<input class="input" placeholder="Suchtext eingeben" *ngIf="!selected" 
  (focus)="isOpened=true" 
  (keydown.enter)="selectItem()" 
  (keydown.tab)="isOpened=false; true"     <!-- append `true` here -->
  (click)="isOpened=true" 
  [(ngModel)]="searchText" 
  (ngModelChange)="filterItems()"
>
```